# Custom \chapter definition

Tags: macros

Can someone tell me why

```
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\stdchapter{#1}}
```

isn't safe to do? Nevermind why I'm asking, I have workarounds so this is more about LaTeX not behaving the way I thought it would. The `\let` command should backup the original `\chapter` definition as `\stdchapter`, and redefining `\chapter` to expand to `\stdchapter` should make it do exactly what it did in the first place. However, LaTeX fails to process my document if I make this change (error message: "`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`").

**UPDATE:**
Here's minimal code needed to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\stdchapter{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

you have to catch the star version of `\chapter`

```
\documentclass[openany]{report}

\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*\chapter{%
  \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
\newcommand*\starchapter[1]{\stdchapter*{#1}}
\def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{\stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\chapter*{baz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's note that this is a nice demonstration of the usage of `\@dblarg` !

Answer (score 12):

It's difficult to say right away what's the source of the problem. Your redefinition should work reasonably, albeit not being what I'd recommend.

The `\chapter` macro usually has *no* argument. It *appears* to have an optional and a mandatory argument, but it really hasn't and this should be taken into consideration when doing redefinitions.

For example, the definition of `\chapter` in the `book` class is

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

which shows that `\chapter` doesn't look for arguments.

I can understand that your example is just an example, but in that way you lose all facilities provided by `\chapter` (*-form and optional argument).

Why you get *that* error surely depends on how you're actually redefining `\chapter`.

Let's see why you get the error in your example. The macro `\tableofcontents` issues `\chapter*{\contentsname}` and here's where your redefinition fails: the argument to `\chapter` is `*`.

The argument to a command is either the text contained in the braced group that follows the command or, if an open brace doesn't immediately follow, the first token (different from a space).

Comment: It could be that some other package is also modifying \chapter, and that's why it fails. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @HaakonRiiser Would you try and present a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem? Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: fwiw, the code as presented works for me; class book, definition after `\begin{document}` (and of course before the first `\chapter` command)

Comment: Thank you for explaining how the starred version causes this problem, and to Herbert for providing a full example! I'm not actually going to use this is my thesis as it was cleaner to just make a new chapter macro with a different name, but it bugged me that I didn't understand why the redefinition didn't work. :)

Comment: @HaakonRiiser It's generally unwise to redefine a macro that could be used in internals changing also its syntax: if it has no arguments, then its redefinition shouldn't have them either.